# Video stop randomly (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

Does anyone know why a video stops playing? It breaks randomly. Not always at the same time.

Build a video wall of 3x3 monitors. Each one has a raspberry pi that receives the video and cuts it to be displayed. The project is https://piwall.co.uk/

Thanks

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pi/Videos/videowall-edit80.mp4 -vcodec copy -f avi -an udp://239.0.1.23:1234?buffer_size=327680B
```

> frame=  471 fps= 30 q=-1.0 size=   15983kB time=00:00:15.69 bitrate=8340.1kbits/frame=  484 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16507kB time=00:00:16.13 bitrate=8382.2kbits/s speed=   1x
> video:16498kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.055688%
> Exiting normally, received signal 15.

Comment: That's [`SIGTERM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723626) meaning something/someone outside of ffmpeg is terminating it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will see what could be the reason. What I notice is that the raspberry pi have different hours but after I change the time it returns to the one it had. Maybe that can be a bug for ffmpeg